# How can I prevent Google Sheets from changing fractions into dates?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to add fractions to Google Sheets document. However, any time I enter `1/12`, it's automatically converted to the date `1/12/2017`

[image: Fraction being converted to a date]

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 10):

**Short version: Use the custom number format `_# ??/??` for regular fractions, or `# ??/??` for mixed fractions.**

---

Add an `=` sign so the cell contains `=1/12`. If it doesn't display as the decimal number `0.08333`, reset the cell's formatting with `Format -> Number -> Automatic`.

[image: Numbers displayed as decimals]

To make the cell display as a fraction, we can use a custom number format courtesy of [math-faq.com](http://math-faq.com/wp/question/how-can-you-format-numbers-as-fractions-in-google-sheets/). Highlight the cells you want to format and select `Format -> Number -> More Formats -> Custom number format...`. To format as a fraction, enter the number format `_# ??/??`.

[image: Numbers displayed as fractions] 
[image: Custom number format for fractions]

***Bonus Tip:*** If you want to use mixed fractions, remove the `_` and use the number format `# ??/??`.

[image: Numbers displayed as mixed numbers]
[image: Custom number format for mixed numbers]

Comment: or for short vulgar fractions, `# ?/??`

Comment: When typing a fraction directly, such as 3/16, this doesn't work. The fraction is immediately converted to a date, like 3/16/2019

Comment: Also, note that this won't work for fractions with hundreds in them (e.g. `1/100` will instead display as `1/99`.) For that you'll need something like `# ???/???`.

Answer (score 0):

To stop Google Sheets from changing your fractions to the date, simply go to `Format>Number>Plain Text`
This will change it so that instead of trying to alter the numbers you enter, it will simply leave it alone.